# Hiding Arrows Based on Horizontal Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I'm struggling to make a tiny change in this horizontal scroll code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lpjj3n1e/

I want to make the **right button** disappear when you scroll all the way to the **right** (just like it happens with the **left button** in the original code).

There should be a quick and easy solution but I haven't been able to find one. Please help me and thank you in advance!

```
     $(function() {
       var print = function(msg) {
         alert(msg);
       };

       var setInvisible = function(elem) {
         elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
       };
       var setVisible = function(elem) {
         elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
       };

       var elem = $("#elem");
       var items = elem.children();

       // Inserting Buttons
       elem.prepend('<div id="right-button" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#"><</a></div>');
       elem.append('  <div id="left-button"><a href="#">></a></div>');

       // Inserting Inner
       items.wrapAll('<div id="inner" />');

       // Inserting Outer
       debugger;
       elem.find('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"/>');

       var outer = $('#outer');

       var updateUI = function() {
         var maxWidth = outer.outerWidth(true);
         var actualWidth = 0;
         $.each($('#inner >'), function(i, item) {
           actualWidth += $(item).outerWidth(true);
         });

         if (actualWidth <= maxWidth) {
           setVisible($('#left-button'));
         }
       };
       updateUI();

       $('#right-button').click(function() {
         var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
         outer.animate({
           scrollLeft: leftPos - 200
         }, 800, function() {
           debugger;
           if ($('#outer').scrollLeft() <= 0) {
             setInvisible($('#right-button'));
           }
         });
       });

       $('#left-button').click(function() {
         setVisible($('#right-button'));
         var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
         outer.animate({
           scrollLeft: leftPos + 200
         }, 800);
       });

       $(window).resize(function() {
         updateUI();
       });
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem seems to be that on clicking the left button there is no function to check whether the arrow should be removed or not.

To test for this we can use the actualWidth which has already been calculated (but it needs to be made more global so its declaration has moved).

There is another small thing which needs rectification - if the maxWidth is greater than the actualWidth there is no need for the arrows. In the code below therefore setVisible has become setVisibleIfNeeded

Here is the revised JS - the original was taken from the jsfiddle. There is a NOTE beside each alteration.

```
  $(function() {
   var print = function(msg) {
     alert(msg);
   };

   var setInvisible = function(elem) {
     elem.css('visibility', 'hidden');
   };
   var setVisibleIfNeeded = function(elem) {
     if (actualWidth>maxWidth) {//NOTE we don't want to show the arrows if there is space in the div for everything without the need to scroll
       elem.css('visibility', 'visible');
     }
   };

   var elem = $("#elem");
   var items = elem.children();

   // Inserting Buttons
   elem.prepend('<div id="right-button" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#"><</a></div>');
   elem.append('  <div id="left-button" style="visibility: hidden;"><a href="#">></a></div>');//NOTE: visibility set to hidden

   // Inserting Inner
   items.wrapAll('<div id="inner" />');

   // Inserting Outer
   debugger;
   elem.find('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"/>');

   var outer = $('#outer');
   var actualWidth=0;//NOTE the declaration is moved up here from the function it was in
   var maxwidth=0;//ditto
   
   var updateUI = function() {
     maxWidth = outer.outerWidth(true);
     actualWidth = 0;
     $.each($('#inner >'), function(i, item) {
       actualWidth += $(item).outerWidth(true);
     });
     setVisibleIfNeeded($('#left-button'));
   };
   updateUI();  

   $('#right-button').click(function() {
     setVisibleIfNeeded($('#left-button'));//NOTE added
     var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
     outer.animate({
       scrollLeft: leftPos - 200
     }, 800, function() {
       debugger;
       if ($('#outer').scrollLeft() <= 0) {
         setInvisible($('#right-button'));
       }
     });
   });

   $('#left-button').click(function() {
     setVisibleIfNeeded($('#right-button'));
     var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
     outer.animate({
       scrollLeft: leftPos + 200
     }, 800,function() {//NOTE function added here to get rid of left button 
      if (leftPos>=(actualWidth-400)) {setInvisible($('#left-button'));}
     });
   });

   $(window).resize(function() {
     updateUI();
   });
 });
```